# Actualizar app play store manteniendo nombres de los paquetes

Tags: android, google-play

Estoy intentando publicar una actualización de la app, para ello he tenido en cuenta las exigencias de que la versión de la actualización sea mayor y que el nombre del paquete sea el mismo (estos puntos están listados en la página de soporte de [Google play console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=es-419)).

Respecto a esto último, estoy teniendo problemas, y es que me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> *"El nombre del paquete del APK debe ser com.xxx.yyy."*

No obstante, y como ya he indicado, el paquete ya es este, tanto el que aparece en el manifest como el que alberga los .java:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.xxx.yyy">
```

Cabe destacar que estos paquetes no se llamaban así cuando importé este proyecto, sino que los he **refactorizado** para que sus nombres coincidan con los de los paquetes de la app que subí en su momento.

¿Hay algún problema con eso? ¿He hecho algo mal? Si en el manifest ya aparece que el paquete es el solicitado, ¿A qué se debe el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira que coincidan tanto el `package` del **Manifest** como el  `applicationId` del **gradle** ya que al hacer la refactorización puede darse el caso que no se haya cambiado en alguno de los sitios

**Manifest**

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.xxx.yyy">
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
```

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber podido resolver tu problema

Comment: siento reabrir el tema pero ahora desde que he cambiado eso, la apk se detiene.¿Sabes por qué puede ser?

Comment: @pepito ¿que error te está dando?

Comment: no hay ningún error aparente, ni tampoco al emularlo, pero al instalarla dice que se ha detenido y se cierra.

Comment: Pues no sabría decirte, ¿has probado a  ver si sale algún error por el logcat al intentar instalarla?